# Flexslider - how to setup min-height?

Tags: jquery, flexslider, css

I'm using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) to create a very simple full-width slideshow on a site I'm working on.

My example: http://hammr.co/3008537/4/index.html

However, what I'm looking for is to have the images always span the whole width of the window, but stop resizing height after reaching a set value and then just cut the side of the image.

This is exactly what happens here: http://www.orient-express.com/web/orex/collection/trains/venice_simplon_orient_express.jsp – after reaching a certain size, the image doesn't resize anymore, just gets cut off.

I dug through the scripts and css on that site but can't figure that out. Setting min-height anywhere for the slides makes them distort, obviously. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for exactly the same thing!
Turns out they're using a minimum width on the slider images in your example:

```
.flexslider .slides img {min-width:1200px; }
```

But in their example the image gets cut off from the right, I want the image to be centered at all times so I found this post: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=323

Let's say I want my image to be at least 480px wide. If my screen width will be smaller then that, it will center my image and it will cut the left and right side equally.

I'm also using a responsive image loader script so smaller images will be loaded on smaller screens: https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

This is my markup for this setup:

```
<div class="flexslider">
 <ul class="slides">
  <li class="slide full">
    <div class="centered">
        <?php
        $myimg['desktop'] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
        $myimg['tablet'] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
        $myimg['phone'] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
        $alt = get_post_meta( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        if ( $myimg['desktop'][0] ): ?>
            <span data-picture="data-picture" data-alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                <span class="sml" data-src="<?php echo $myimg['phone'][0]; ?>"></span>
                <span class="med" data-src="<?php echo $myimg['tablet'][0]; ?>" data-media="(min-width:480px)"></span>
                <span class="lrg" data-src="<?php echo $myimg['desktop'][0]; ?>" data-media="(min-width:760px)"></span>
                <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
                    <span data-src="<?php echo $myimg['desktop'][0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>"></span>
                <![endif]-->
                <noscript>
                    <img src="<?php echo $myimg['desktop'][0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                </noscript>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is my CSS for this setup:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    .flexslider .slides > li.full {
        margin:0 auto !important;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        overflow:hidden;
    }   
    .flexslider .slides > li.full .centered {
        position:relative;
        right:50% !important;
        text-align:center;
    }   
    .flexslider .slides > li.full .centered img {
        min-width:480px !important;
        display:inline-block !important;
        margin-right:-100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me make this work with Slick Slider as well. Just add the `.centered` div around the image, and then adjust the css class names accordingly to match your markup.